# Very low disk performance on Samba

Tags: debian, networking, windows, samba, io

I'm using Samba on Debian 8.4 (Jessie) to share files with a small number of Windows & Mac users (~20 total, ~5 at a time at most) and I'm seeing abysmal performance on read and write: tested by copying large file to and from the share, average < 500 KB/s.

I tested the disk by running `dd if=/dev/zero of=/srv/temp.tmp ...` and `dd if=/srv/temp.tmp of=/dev/null ...` and the disk can get to 70~80 MB/s so that's probably not the bottleneck.

I tested network by running `iperf` and even on the edge of the wifi I can get 4~5MB/s, in door it's ~10MB/s so I don't think it's network related either.

An interesting observation is that during my test (copying large file to/from the share) while running `iostat -d -p md0 1` shows that the disk is not active all the time, but rather only read/write 1 sec for every ~10 sec inactive. This is not the case during the test with `dd`.

All the tests were performed when I was the only active user to rule out possible interferences. This is a fresh install of Debian with some other stuff (apache server, php, etc) and a default config of samba. The share config is as follow

```
[share]
  path = /srv
  force group = data
  read only = No
  create mask = 0660
  force create mode = 0660
  directory mask = 02770
  force directory mode = 02770
```

Comment: Are you sure your network is in MB/s and not Mb/s ? (Megabits, ie 8 times less information than a MegaByte [Byte=8bits]) ,  as 10Mbits/sec would yield what speed you are witnessing (the rest being taken up by other paquets). And then check https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/speed.html  for a bunch of things to look for (read size, etc)

Comment: Pretty sure it's megabyte, not megabit. `iperf` result is in megabit which I had divided by 8 before posting that to keep all the numbers consistent.

Answer (score 0):

To tune performance of Samba, the howto has a section about speed/performance tuning:

https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/speed.html

You can probably enhance your results by tuning : the read size, and the socket options, in particular, are worth tweaking.